# Is there a way for this script to happen when a row is filled out as opposed to doing a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a sample log where multiple staff book in samples on this sheet. We generally start entering with the name of the sample, then fill out type of sample- this causes onEdit function to happen.

With the 2nd script, createnewsampleresultsheet I am trying to achieve two things- for it to execute when a row is filled out- at the moment it is doing a loop based on what has already been entered and it's also not efficient as it will continue creating the files as column A (sample id) is already filled from 001 to 1000(as an example).

The 2nd thing i'm wanting it to do is to insert the link of the newly created sheet back into the sample ID of the corresponding row- ie 001 text becomes a clickable link.

I've included a link to a google sheet which contains some sample data.

Hopefully someone can help with this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bW01-4l9odsiu6YZlu1Kj7hk1d-gWp8uwRKwXRARUtY/edit#gid=120163269

The script:-

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheets = "Analysis Log";
  if (sheets.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()) === -1 || e.range.getColumn() !== 4) return;
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  var newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
  e.range.offset(0, -2).setValue(newdate).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
}
function Createnewsampleresultsheet() {
 
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Analysis Log'); 
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
 
  console.log(lastRow); 
  
 
 for (let i = 0; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    let Sample_name = sheet.getRange(8+i,5).getValue(); 
    let Sample_id = sheet.getRange(8+i, 1).getValue(); 
    let Sample_type = sheet.getRange(8+i, 4).getValue();
    let Date = sheet.getRange(8+i, 2).getValue();
    let Time= sheet.getRange(8+i, 3).getValue();
   
    console.log(i + ": " + Sample_name + " | " + Sample_id); 
 
    //Setting titles values for result sheet
    let result_sheet = Sample_name + "-" + Sample_id
    
    //Create result sheet 
    console.log("Sample result sheet ", "Sample_name"); 
    let destination_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mErM-8b9n-H1BXrJXrRX19F6GPVMbSce'); 
    let new_samplesheet = DriveApp.getFileById('1ZDy5K4l1qhQXbYsRKNBQyscU_qX_YDEMa216TaBp6iM').makeCopy(result_sheet, destination_folder).getId(); 
    console.log(new_samplesheet); 
 
    //Get new sample sheet

     ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(new_samplesheet); 
    let sampleresult = ss.getSheetByName("Sample results template"); 
 
    // Sample information 
    sampleresult.getRange("C2").setValue(Sample_id); 
    sampleresult.getRange("C3").setValue(Sample_name); 
    sampleresult.getRange("C4").setValue(Sample_type); 
    sampleresult.getRange("C5").setValue(Date); 
    sampleresult.getRange("C6").setValue(Time); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column to verify whether that line has already been dealt with or not (I added selection buttons in your sample sheet. I recommend you to add the selection buttons all the way down, as they look nice and clean).

Then do it like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  if (sheet.getRange(8 + i, 8).getValue() == 'false') {

    // the rest of your code here

  }
}
```

Now, regarding your 2nd question. To add a link, you must use `new_samplesheet` to create a URL for the new sheet and then edit the name column as a link. To do this, at the end of the for loop, add this:

```js
sheet.getRange(8+i,5).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + new_samplesheet + '", "' + Sample_name + '")');
sheet.getRange(8+i,8).setValue('true'); //this is necessary for the first part of the answer to work
```

Comment: Thanks for that I hadn't thought of doing a if condition based on tick boxes. Would it take a while to run if we have upwards to 3000 samples lines? If so, would it be better to get rid of the loop and do the function as a cell in column D is completed?

Comment: I'm testing the first part of your suggestion and i got this:- Syntax error: SyntaxError: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name line: 22 file: Create sample result sheet.gs

I got rid of the 2nd let in the IF argument (if i'm using the term incorrectly- please read as line) so it's now 

 for (let i = 0, isCreated = false; i <= lastRow && isCreated == false; i++) {

And I've ticked up to row 13 with the files to those rows made up beforehand so i should expect to see the script start making files from row 14 onwards however it reproduces files row 8 onwards. What's the issue?

Comment: I have simplified the answer. I got rid of the variable isCreated and now it will simply check whether the box is checked or not. It should work now.